# load wp_editor without wp_footer

Tags: wp-editor

Im trying to laod wp_editor in a popup and I don't want to use wp_footer and fill it with lot of unnecessary js, css and html loaded by other plugins.

At the moment when i need wp_editor I have:

```
//if using wp_editor load necesary files
if (  class_exists( '_WP_Editors' ) ):

        _WP_Editors::editor_js();
        _WP_Editors::enqueue_scripts();
endif;
```

But I still need wp_footer....
There is any way to run the tinymce editor without wp_footer?

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say "popup"? is it a new browser window or something like lightbox?

Comment: A New browser window